# Machines with identical number of vCPUs, one gives MPI Error, the other does not

Tags: 18.04, cpu, mpi

**TLDR**

Two machines with the same number of vCPUs allow different number of MPI threads. Why?

---

I am running two Ubuntu instances:

1. Deep Learning Base AMI (Ubuntu 18.04) Version 20.2 (ami-0c8466c376c0d21e1)
2. Deep Learning AMI (Ubuntu 18.04) Version 25.3 (ami-0cfb96b24266ec1ce)

Both have 32 vCPUs, with 16 cores and 2 threads per core.

AMI instance 2 is able to run `mpirun -np 19 python3` while AMI instance 1 gives the error:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
There are not enough slots available in the system to satisfy the 19
slots that were requested by the application:

  python3

Either request fewer slots for your application, or make more slots
available for use.
```

Why am I limited to 16 MPI processes on AMI1 but can run 19+ AMI processes on AMI2?

---

I ran `lscpu`:

**AMI 1:**

```
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              32
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-31
Thread(s) per core:  2
Core(s) per socket:  16
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               79
Model name:          Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2686 v4 @ 2.30GHz
Stepping:            1
CPU MHz:             1683.161
CPU max MHz:         3000.0000
CPU min MHz:         1200.0000
BogoMIPS:            4600.14
Hypervisor vendor:   Xen
Virtualization type: full
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            256K
L3 cache:            46080K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-31
```

**AMI2**

```
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              32
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-31
Thread(s) per core:  2
Core(s) per socket:  16
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               79
Model name:          Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2686 v4 @ 2.30GHz
Stepping:            1
CPU MHz:             2237.235
CPU max MHz:         3000.0000
CPU min MHz:         1200.0000
BogoMIPS:            4600.14
Hypervisor vendor:   Xen
Virtualization type: full
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            256K
L3 cache:            46080K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-31
```

Answer (score 0):

AMI 1 is not running at its top speed https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/xeon_e5/e5-2686_v4 
 whereas AMI 2 is. I would swap the CPUs and see if the problem moves; if it does, you have a defective CPU to [return to Intel under warranty](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005494/processors.html).